# Click handler (not inline) not working on same domain iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a click handler to iframe elements (iframe is part of the page, not added by me, and is same domain), but it doesn't seem to work. If I change the event to 'mouseenter', it works fine, but what I'm trying to do lends itself better to being done with a click.  From what I understand, even if there are already existing click methods on the element, I can still add another and they would run in the order they were attached.  Does this mean that one of the existing click handlers is somehow stopping mine from running, since mouseenter works fine, or is this something else happening?  I'm using jQuery 3.2.1.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const INSTRUCTOR_PLACEHOLDER = 'Staff';
  const IFRAME_ID = 'ptifrmtgtframe';
  let iframe = document.getElementById(IFRAME_ID);
  $(iframe).on('load', function () {

    let instructorElementIds = 'span[id ^= "MTG_INSTR$"]';
    //Issue here
    $(iframe.contentDocument.body).on('click', instructorElementIds, function(event) {
      console.log('i run');
    });
  });
});
```

iframe here: https://pastebin.com/qwAmCFJx

full html page (can't load in browser since there's some authorization): https://pastebin.com/S4RhJuW8

EDIT:
After trying to do it without jquery I noticed that anywhere in the table of listings doesn't respond to my click event, but it seems that everywhere else in the iframe does.  The table id is ACE_SSR_CLSRSLT_WRK_GROUPBOX1 in the html source that i posted to pastebin, if that helps.  This is the code for that:

```
iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('test');
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == 'span' && e.target.id.startsWith('MTG_INSTR$')) {
      console.log('hello');
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please add enough of your source HTML so that we can try to reproduce the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is the iframe source sufficient?  Or the entire html + iframe?  I'm having trouble getting the main html and iframe source copied all together.  I've posted the iframe though and will try to get the entire source onto one page.

Comment: Try without jQuery.

Comment: `iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log('test');
      if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == 'span' && e.target.id.startsWith('MTG_INSTR$')) {
          console.log('hello');
      }
    });`  I tried this, but it didn't work.  Not sure how to format code in the comments properly.  'test' was output into the console for the empty space, but not when I clicked anywhere in the table of data (of which the element i want a click handler on is in).  Double checked that that table wasn't in another iframe just to be sure, and it's not.

Comment: Maybe that iframe's script intercepts the click and does stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation(). You can try using a capturing event listener on the first target (`window`) for the first event in the click cycle (`mousedown`): iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('mousedown', console.log, **true**)

Comment: Mousedown and mouseup both work, and I'm fine with mousedown after reading the differences, besides maybe mouse middle and right click also triggering them but I can fix that with an 'if' statement.  If those work, does that mean the event isn't being propagated?  If so, in the spirit of answering the question, is there a way to bypass that?